# How do create a multi select options? or add attributes to the models.CharField

Tags: django, django-models

I have this

```
models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=LOCATION_NAME)
```

However, I want it to render something like this,

```
<select multiple="multiple">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to add this to the django admin section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render it using the SelectMultiple Widget:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SelectMultiple

You'll probably be using a MultipleChoiceField in your form:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield

Comment: Yes. If you're referencing other models, you'll use a ModelMultipleChoiceField (as in the many-to-many in the admin). Otherwise, you'll need to specify how you want to serialize the results of your MultipleChoiceField into your CharField.

Comment: Given your example, you might want to use a CommaSeparatedIntegerField in your model.

Answer (score 2):

Make a ModelForm for your model and manually set what widget you want the field to show as:

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**forms.py**

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    publisher = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

This means the HTML used to display the field is a **select**, the form generates the data as a list of publishers, and your valid choice is saved simply as a character field in the database. You don't actually need to specify widget=forms.SelectMultiple but it's good to see what's happening (and I always confuse the different fields when talking about database/form/widget)

Comment: I had to change 'forms.MultipleChoiceField' above to 'forms.CharField' for the options to show up, then it worked.